# How to match from start and end and, replace string in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to change a string/line of a file `main.js` from another file `replace.js`

I want to change the `server` property dynamically based on machine `ip`

**main.js**

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  server: `http://localhost:3000`,
  apikey: `X199`
};
```

**replace.js**

```
const replace = require('replace-in-file')
const address = require('address')

replace({
    files: 'main.js',
    from: /^server:\..*3000,$/g,
    to: `http://${address.ip()}:3000`
})
```

I have tested multiple regex but none was working for me.

Comment: Not sure but if you want to match `server: \`http://localhost:3000\`,` you have to remove matching the literal dot and add a `\`` after 3000 like `^server:.*3000\`,$` see https://regex101.com/r/WJkRY6/1

Comment: used something like this but didn't work `/^server:.*3000\`,$/gm`

Comment: @Thefourthbird as per your recommended site, regex is working fine but not in `replace-in-file` npm package that I am using

Comment: Did you try it without the anchors? `/server:\..*3000,/g` or match leading whitespace characters `/^\s*server:\..*3000,$/g`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
replace({
    files: 'main.js',
    from: /server:\s*[`'"]https?:\/\/.*?[`'"],/g,
    to: `server: 'http://${address.ip()}:3000',`
})
```

The anchor tags ^$ is not needed because the string 'server: http://localhost:3000' is not started at the very beginning of the file, and is not ended at the very end of the file.